# Obtaining mean of rasters

Tags: r, spatial, terra

I want to get a mean chlorophyll a from the 3 .nc files below, and am wondering if using mosaic is the correct thing to do?

https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/AQUA_MODIS.20020101_20021231.L3m.YR.NSST.sst.4km.nc
https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/AQUA_MODIS.20030101_20031231.L3m.YR.NSST.sst.4km.nc
https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/AQUA_MODIS.20040101_20041231.L3m.YR.NSST.sst.4km.nc

```
library(terra)

#List of .nc files in directory
fls <- list.files("/folder/with/files", ".nc$", full.names = TRUE)

#list of rast objects
r_list <- lapply(fls, rast)

#create spatial raster collection
coll <- sprc(r_list)

#Get the mean values across all rasters
chla_m<-mosaic(coll, fun="mean")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(terra)

#List of .nc files in directory
fls <- list.files("/folder/with/files", ".nc$", full.names = TRUE)

#list to SpatRaster object conversion
r_list <- rast(fls)

#For global mean calculation i.e. single mean for the entire SpatRaster
global(r_list, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

#For local mean calculation i.e. pixel-wise mean calculation
mean(r_list, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Simple and works! The output is exactly the same as mosaic has given me too. Thanks for this

Answer (score -1):

`terra::mosaic()` is intended to spatially merge a set of rasters. In the overlapping cells you can apply a function to determine the value to set the cell to, `mean` is the default. So yes, your approach would work but it is terribly inefficient.

In good old plain `R` you could do:

```
library(abind)

# Get a list of all files to be merged
lf <- list.files("/folder/with/files", "^AQUA.*nc$", full.names = T)

# Read in all the data
d <- apply(lf, function(f) {n <- nc_open(f); x <- ncvar_get(n, "sst"); nc_close(n); x})

# Turn the list of data matrices into an array
arr <- abind(d, along = 3)

# Calculate the mean over the 3rd dimension of the array to create a matrix
sst <- rowMeans(arr, na.rm = T, dims = 2)
```

You can convert the `sst` matrix into a `terra` `SpatRaster` if so desired.

This snippet of code does all you need and nothing else, so rather efficient.

**Memory limitations**

If you have to merge many files in this way, or you use a different data set whose dimensions are larger, you may run into memory problems that will dramatically slow down the process. If that is the case, use a loop instead. The loop overhead will be completely dwarfed by the rest of the code (mostly reading the data).

```
# Get a list of all files to be merged
lf <- list.files("/folder/with/files", "^AQUA.*nc$", full.names = T)

# Function to calculate mean SST from multiple MODIS AQUA files
sst <- function(lf) {
  for (ndx in 1:length(lf)) {
    n <- nc_open(lf[[ndx]])
    if (ndx == 1) {
      data <- ncvar_get(n, "sst")
    } else {
      data <- data + ncvar_get(n, "sst")
    }
    nc_close(n)
  }
  data / length(lf)
}
```

The trick here is that there is never more large memory demand than for two matrices: the `data` object and the data read in by `ncvar_get()`.